# Maven jetty plugin - delay when starting in background mode

Tags: java, unix, maven-2, background, jetty

I start a jetty server on linux using

`nohup mvn jetty:run &`

to run it in background and to stay when I quit from the console. Usually (mvn jetty:run) it starts in seconds, but in this case it takes about minute to start. What can be the cause of such a delay?

Stack trace

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0-b16 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004bba8c00 nid=0x560a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Timer-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaac053d800 nid=0x55fb in Object.wait() [0x0000000042392000..0x0000000042392b90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaae554f40> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
        - locked <0x00002aaaae554f40> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

"StopJettyPluginMonitor" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaac04b4c00 nid=0x55fa runnable [0x0000000042291000..0x0000000042291b10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
        - locked <0x00002aaaae453860> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.util.Monitor.run(Monitor.java:74)

"Timer-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004b5cf800 nid=0x55f9 in Object.wait() [0x0000000040c78000..0x0000000040c78a90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaaeea00b8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
        - locked <0x00002aaaaeea00b8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

"1455093129@qtp-422797318-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080" prio=10 tid=0x000000004b6d9800 nid=0x55f7 runnable [0x000000004130c000..0x000000004130ca10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:215)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
        - locked <0x00002aaaae44ac10> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$1)
        - locked <0x00002aaaae44abf8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00002aaaae44a588> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:459)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:192)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:124)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:706)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)

"91446054@qtp-422797318-0" prio=10 tid=0x000000004b621400 nid=0x55f6 in Object.wait() [0x000000004120b000..0x000000004120bd90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaab1171890> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:563)
        - locked <0x00002aaab1171890> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread)

"pool-1-thread-5" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaac15d4c00 nid=0x55f5 in Object.wait() [0x0000000041a4f000..0x0000000041a4fd10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"pool-1-thread-4" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaac0134000 nid=0x55f4 in Object.wait() [0x000000004194e000..0x000000004194ec90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"pool-1-thread-3" prio=10 tid=0x000000004ba72800 nid=0x55f3 in Object.wait() [0x0000000042190000..0x0000000042190c10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"pool-1-thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x000000004b8b6c00 nid=0x55f2 in Object.wait() [0x000000004208f000..0x000000004208fb90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x000000004b8b6400 nid=0x55f1 in Object.wait() [0x0000000040415000..0x0000000040415b10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafff4580> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004affd800 nid=0x55eb runnable [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004affb800 nid=0x55ea waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000041d8b4d0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004aff7800 nid=0x55e9 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000041c8a450]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004aff5c00 nid=0x55e8 runnable [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000041b8a820]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004afd2400 nid=0x55e7 in Object.wait() [0x000000004184d000..0x000000004184db10]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafdf0450> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafdf0450> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004afd0800 nid=0x55e6 in Object.wait() [0x000000004174c000..0x000000004174ca90]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaaafdf0530> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0x00002aaaafdf0530> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x000000004af6e000 nid=0x55e4 in Object.wait() [0x000000004072f000..0x0000000040730ed0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00002aaab1196b60> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool.join(QueuedThreadPool.java:298)
        - locked <0x00002aaab1196b60> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Lock)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.join(Jetty6PluginServer.java:206)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:461)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:553)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:523)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000004afcb000 nid=0x55e5 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000004b000000 nid=0x55ec waiting on condition

JNI global references: 861
```

Answer (score 5):

I get so tired of watching people abuse `nohup`.  Here's how *real* daemonization routines work:

1. Create a child process.
2. Launch daemon as a child of that child process.
3. Exit the first process.

A simple way to emulate this using `sh` is as follows.

`sh -c "mvn jetty:run &"`

Observe...

```
scott@optimusprime:~/code/leapfrog/lasso> sh -c "mvn jetty:run &"
scott@optimusprime:~/code/leapfrog/lasso> ps aux | grep jetty:run
scott    26165 45.5  5.8 813556 235764 pts/9   Sl   15:23   0:06 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun//bin/java -Xmx512M -classpath /home/scott/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1//boot/classworlds-1.1.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/scott/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1//bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/home/scott/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1/ org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher "jetty:run"
scott@optimusprime:~/code/leapfrog/lasso> exit
```

If I check my process list from a separate terminal, or later, the program is still running.

However I have to ask, why do this instead of just install your web application in a local application server, and start it?  Hopefully you aren't managing your *real* environments using apache maven.

Comment: But what's wrong with nohup usage?

Maven-based deployment was on the development env only, of course.

Comment: What's wrong with `nohup` is it tends to mean shutdown requires a subsequent `SIGTERM`, which otherwise is unnecessary.  That is, *well* behaved processes actually do shut down when they get a `SIGHUP`, so `nohup` is actually just a cheap trick.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the explanation. Using nohup definitely is not a good idea, but anyway the cause of the problem is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would run it in the foreground, and trigger a thread dump (Ctrl+Break), and see what it's doing by inspecting each thread stack trace. Without any further information I can't offer any more advice.

Comment: thanks for the tip Brian
posted the stack trace below.
Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using `screen`. Might be overkill for such a simple task, but you can wrap it in a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Using maven is very convenient to download, install and start an application.  Among many other benefits, maven offers developers the ability to manage the version of Jetty.  Using the advice provided here I think maven fits the bill as a production initiation mechanism.